# Prove that $P_{f}(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{l} (X - a_i)^{n_i} \prod_{j=1}^{m} (X^2 + a_jX + b_j)^{q_j} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

> Let $f$ be a linear map in a real finite dimension vector space $E$.
>
> Prove that the characteristic polynomial of $f$ can be factorized in the form:
>
> $P_{f}(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{l} (X - a_i)^{n_i} \prod_{j=1}^{m} (X^2 + a_jX + b_j)^{q_j} $

---

I have thought of using proof by induction.

In one dimensional vector space, it is true.

If we suppose it is true for dimension $n$.

For the case of $n +1$, let $g$ be linear map in an $(n+1)$ dimension vector space.

If we wrote the matrix of $g$ in a basis, we'll have:

$P_g(X) = (a_{11} - X) P(X) + R(X) $

$P(X)$ can be factorized since it is the characteristic polynomial of degree $n$.

I do not know how to get the full factorization of the polynomial.

I might be wrong using the induction, another method would be appreciated.

Comment: Over what field?  In $\mathbb{R}$, all monics factor like that..

Comment: @Dzoooks Over the field of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly algebra of polynomials rather than linear algebra. In fact:

> Any polynomial $P(X)\in\mathbb R[X]$ can be written in the form
>
> $$P(X)=\lambda\left(\prod_{i=1}^l(X-a_i)^{n_i}\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^m(X^2+b_iX+c_i)^{q_i}\right)$$
>
> where $l,m,n_i,q_i\in\mathbb N$, $\lambda,a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb R$ and $b_i^2-4c_i<0$. (notice that $\lambda$ is the leading coefficient of $P(X)$)

For the above to hold, keep in mind the convention $\prod_{i=1}^0\alpha_i=1$ for any $\alpha_i$.

Now for your exercise, you know that the leading coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda=1$.

To prove the fact stated above, use the fundamental theorem of algebra, which says that any non constant polynomial over $\mathbb C$ has at least one root. In particular, given a non constant polynomial $P(X)\in\mathbb R[X]$, you know that it has at least one root $z\in\mathbb C$. So $P(X)=(X-z)Q(X)$ with $\deg Q(X)<\deg P(X)$. With this you can prove by induction that $$P(X)=\lambda \prod_{i=1}^n(X-z_i)^{n_i}$$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is the leading coefficient of $P(X)$, $n_i\in\mathbb N$ and $z_i\in\mathbb C$.

- If all the roots of $P(X)$ are real, we're done: all $z_i\in\mathbb R$.
- If $P(X)$ has no real root, then all the $z_i$ are in $\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb R$. Now, you notice that $P(\overline{z_i})=\overline{P(z_i)}=0$ because the coefficients of $P(X)$ are real, and because $z_i\notin\mathbb R$, $\overline{z_i}\neq z_i$. So you can actually write your polynomial in the form $$\prod_{i=1}^m(X-z_i)^{q_i}(X-\overline{z_i})^{q_i}.$$ Notice that $(X-z_i)(X-\overline{z_i})=X^2-2\Re(z_i)X+|z_i|^2.$
- Otherwise, isolate the reals from the non reals, so you can rewrite your polynomial (renaming) as $$P(X)=\lambda\left(\prod_{i=1}^l(X-a_i)^{n_i}\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^m(X-z_i)^{p_i}\right)$$ where $\lambda,a_i\in\mathbb R$, $l,m,n_i,p_i\in\mathbb N$ and $z_i\in\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb R$. Then you can conclude just as above.

Comment: In the case of the characteristic polynomial, the leading coefficient is $(-1)^n$. Thank you for your help. Accepted answer.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi It's a pleasure :) Indeed there are people who define the characteristic polynomial as $\det(A-XI)$, in this case indeed the leading coefficient is $(-1)^n$. Others define it as $\det(XI-A)$, or give an equivalent definition that makes the leading coefficient $1$. Seeing that the $(-1)^n$ is missing in the factorization given in your question, the person who wrote the exercise must assume the latter definition of a characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I have another question, the eigenvalues of $f$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. If a root is a complex number, then we will have: $f(v) =\lambda v $ which is not in a real vector space as stated in the problem.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi You're right. If we're working in a real vector space, complex roots of the characteristic polynomial can not be eigenvalues. But in a complex vector space, this is true, even if your matrice has real coefficients. It's all a matter of where you take the coefficients of your vector. For example, take the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The characteristic polynomial is $X^2+1$. It's roots are $i$ and $-i$. Now, for any $v\in\mathbb R^2$, surely $Av\neq iv$ because $Av$ and $v$ have real coefficients...

Comment: ... Now what happens if you take the vector $v=(1,-i)\in\mathbb C^2$? ;)

Comment: $f$ is considered in a real vector space.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi Then no, nonreal roots of the characteristic polynomial can't be eigenvalues. If $f(v)=zv$ with $z\in\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb R$, notice that $f(v)$ has real coefficients but not $zv$.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi My answer was accepted (green check mark) if I recall. I wonder why was it removed.

Comment: I use a tablet, I must removed it by mistake while scrolling down.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi OK. Thank you!